# Sending a list as a parameter but it keeps sending an empty list

Tags: python

Hello I am writing a blackjack game in Python for fun. I am having a problem with a method called calculateTemporaryHandValueWhereAEquals11() in the player class. It is called by a method in the dealer class called drawCard().The problem is the first if statement. If there is an A in the dealers hand then it will call calculateTemporaryHandValueWhereAEquals11(self.player) to check if the value of hand is = 21 assuming that A will equal 11. For some reason the list is empty and nothing happens in the calculateTemporaryHandValueWhereAEquals11() method. But in the elif statement in drawCards() I call a function called calculateTemporaryHandValueWhere() which checks the value of the hand assuming A is equal to 1. This one one works, it gets the list and calculates the value! I dont understand what I am doing that makes one method work and not the other. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated! Thank You!

```
import random 
class Player(object):    
def drawCard(self, hitOrStop):
    if hitOrStop == 'hit':
        playerRecievesCard = RandomCard().selectRandomCard()
        self.myHand.append(playerRecievesCard)
        return True
    else:
        return False

def calculateTemporaryHandValue(self, playersHand = []):
    sumOfAllCards = 0
    for card in playersHand:
        if card == 'A':
            sumOfAllCards += 1
        elif card == 'J' or card == 'K' or card == 'Q':
            sumOfAllCards += 10
        else:
            sumOfAllCards += card
    return sumOfAllCards
def calculateTemporaryHandValueWhereAEquals11(self, playerHand = []):
    sumOfAllCards = 0
    print(playerHand)
    for card in playerHand:
        if card == 'A':
            sumOfAllCards += 11
        elif card == 'J' or card == 'K' or card == 'Q':
            sumOfAllCards += 10
        else:
            sumOfAllCards += card
    return sumOfAllCards

class Dealer(Player):
def __init__(self):
    self.myHand = []
def drawCards(self):
    if 'A' in self.myHand:
        valueOfdeal = Dealer.calculateTemporaryHandValueWhereAEquals11(self.myHand)
        print (valueOfdeal)
        #if Dealer.calculateTemporaryHandValueWhereAEquals11(self.myHand) <= 21 and Player.calculateTemporaryHandValueWhereAEquals11(self.myHand) >= 17:
        print ("he")
        return False
    elif Dealer.calculateTemporaryHandValue(self.myHand) < 17 and len(self.myHand) <=5:
        playerRecievesCard = RandomCard().selectRandomCard()
        self.myHand.append(playerRecievesCard)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: You will need to edit your code down to a [mcve].

Comment: Think about writing some new code just to try out your understanding. Make it as minimal as possible as @TigerhawkT3 suggests.

Comment: @PeterWood I edited it down to just the important methods.

Comment: It's still too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling the method on the class `Dealer.calculateTemporaryHandValueWhereAEquals11(self.myHand)` but rather the method on the instance `self.calculateTemporaryHandValueWhereAEquals11(self.myHand)`.

When you do that the method gets the argument `self.myHand` as the first argument `self` rather than as the second argument `playerHand`. If the method didn't have a default argument for `playerHand = []`, you would get a `TypeError: [method] takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! @Dan D.